# Loading a compiled .jar library into an Android Project

Tags: android

## UPDATE

This is the correct way to add a compiled library:

1. Download the compiled .jar (and any extra files)
2. Add the jar (and anything extra) to a folder called `libs` in the project.
3. Right click on the project and configure build path
4. Libraries -> Add jar -> choose the jar
5. ...
6. Profit

## ORIGINAL QUESTION

Has anyone come across this before?

http://code.google.com/p/aacdecoder-android/

I am trying (desperately) to get it to work. Here are the steps I've followed:

1. Download the compiled .jar and .so files from downloads (the top one `aacdecoder-android-libs-0.5.zip`).
2. Add the two files to a folder called `lib` in the project.
3. Right click on the project and configure build path
4. Libraries -> Add jar -> choose the jar

I've put in the sample code on the google code page and yet I'm getting this error:

```
W/dalvikvm(  405): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001aa28)
E/AndroidRuntime(  405): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
E/AndroidRuntime(  405): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library aacdecoder not found
E/AndroidRuntime(  405):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:489)
E/AndroidRuntime(  405):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:557)
E/AndroidRuntime(  405):    at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.Decoder.loadLibrary(Decoder.java:167)
E/AndroidRuntime(  405):    at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.Decoder.create(Decoder.java:188)
E/AndroidRuntime(  405):    at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.Decoder.create(Decoder.java:178)
E/AndroidRuntime(  405):    at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.AACPlayer.createDecoder(AACPlayer.java:407)
E/AndroidRuntime(  405):    at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.AACPlayer.<init>(AACPlayer.java:121)
E/AndroidRuntime(  405):    at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.AACPlayer.<init>(AACPlayer.java:104)
E/AndroidRuntime(  405):    at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.AACPlayer.<init>(AACPlayer.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(  405):    at com.tclayson.furadio.FURadioActivity.onCreate(FURadioActivity.java:14)
E/AndroidRuntime(  405):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
E/AndroidRuntime(  405):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
E/AndroidRuntime(  405):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
E/AndroidRuntime(  405):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:116)
E/AndroidRuntime(  405):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
E/AndroidRuntime(  405):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(  405):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(  405):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
E/AndroidRuntime(  405):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  405):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(  405):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
E/AndroidRuntime(  405):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
E/AndroidRuntime(  405):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What am I doing wrong?! Can anyone help? Can anyone get that particular library to work at all? I need to play an AAC stream (eg: http://media-ice.musicradio.com/Capital).

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I added the library files (the .jar and the .so) to a different folder `libs` this time (with `s`).

Going through the same steps as above produces this new error:

```
D/ddm-heap(  436): Got feature list request
D/dalvikvm(  436): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.tclayson.furadio/lib/libaacdecoder.so 0x4376acc8
D/dalvikvm(  436): Added shared lib /data/data/com.tclayson.furadio/lib/libaacdecoder.so 0x4376acc8
D/dalvikvm(  436): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.tclayson.furadio/lib/libaacdecoder.so 0x4376acc8
I/InetAddress(  436): Unknown host media-ice.musicradio.com, throwing UnknownHostException
E/AACPlayer(  436): playAsync():
E/AACPlayer(  436): java.net.SocketException: Permission denied (maybe missing INTERNET permission)
E/AACPlayer(  436):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.createSocketImpl(Native Method)
E/AACPlayer(  436):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.createSocket(OSNetworkSystem.java:85)
E/AACPlayer(  436):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl2.create(PlainSocketImpl2.java:59)
E/AACPlayer(  436):     at java.net.Socket.checkClosedAndCreate(Socket.java:829)
E/AACPlayer(  436):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:984)
E/AACPlayer(  436):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:67)
E/AACPlayer(  436):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionManager$ConnectionPool.getHttpConnection(HttpConnectionManager.java:151)
E/AACPlayer(  436):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionManager.getConnection(HttpConnectionManager.java:73)
E/AACPlayer(  436):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHTTPConnection(HttpURLConnection.java:826)
E/AACPlayer(  436):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:812)
E/AACPlayer(  436):     at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.AACPlayer.play(AACPlayer.java:259)
E/AACPlayer(  436):     at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.AACPlayer$1.run(AACPlayer.java:230)
E/AACPlayer(  436):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1060)
```

What is the problem here? I don't understand the `Unknown host` error, because its evident that the above url exists. If this is a library specific issue then don't worry. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your second question regarding the 'Unknown host' error (which actually says 'Permission denied' in its root cause, which makes more sense): You need to declare the `INTERNET` permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml`, such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="..." [...]>
    [...]
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    [...]
</manifest>
```

For further details about the Android permission concept, refer to: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html

Comment: this was the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try right clicking the project, then going to properties > java build path.

Comment: That's where I end up when I right click and go Build Path > Configure Build Path. :)

Comment: Oh sorry got nothing else for ya then :/.

Comment: damn... :( its killing me this!

Comment: fml! if you see my update, all I needed to do was add a permission! :p

Answer (score 0):

You have to extract the file aacdecoder-android-libs-0.5.zip, this will revleal aacdecoder-android-0.5.jar and a folder named armeabi containing a static library.

To use the library copy the folder and the aacdecoder-android-0.5.jar into your libs folder. And add the jar to your buildpath (as you did with the zip before).